# Strings with variables include namespace and object information?

Tags: string, powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

```
# Locate Local HDD drive letter (100GB+)
#(Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType LIKE 3" | Sort-Object -Descending Size)[0] | Format-List *
$oLocalLargestHDD = (Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk WHERE DriveType LIKE 3" | Sort-Object -Descending Size)[0]
If ($oLocalLargestHDD.Size -gt 100000000)
{
    $sMsg = "HDD ( $oLocalLargestHDD.Name ) is found!"
    Write-Host $sMsg
} else {
    Write-Host "HDD is NOT found!"
}
```

outputs:

> HDD ( \BRIANG\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:".Name ) is found!

instead of

> HDD ( C: ) is found!

Comment: `$sMsg = "HDD $($oLocalLargestHDD.Name) is found!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing variable expansion properly. You need to have a [subexpression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx). You were close.

```
$sMsg = "HDD ($($oLocalLargestHDD.Name)) is found!"
```

Or you can use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx).

```
$sMsg = "HDD ({0}) is found!" -f $oLocalLargestHDD.Name
```

What you were seeing was the string representation of the `$oLocalLargestHDD` object. Using either of the methods above allow you to use the property.

Comment: Matt,  Thank you sir!  I prefer the 2nd of your examples.

Comment: @BrianGonzalez You are most welcome. If this answered your question consider marking it as so with the checkmark to the left.

Comment: Can i use this method when using Write-Host as well?  it doesn't appear to like the "-f" format argument.

Comment: @BrianGonzalez If you put the whole thing in brackets it will be fine. `Write-Host ("HDD ({0}) is found!" -f $oLocalLargestHDD.Name)`